# Why do I get a blank page before title?

Tags: spacing, titles

Why do I get a blank page before the title page with this input?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage[geometry,weather,misc,clock]{ifsym}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}
% \newcommand \defeq {\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\newcommand \catname [1] {\mathcal{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator \defeq {\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\DeclareMathOperator \compose {\circ}
%
%What's wrong with these?
\DeclareMathOperator {\composeh*} {\odot\limit}
\DeclareMathOperator {\composet*} {\cdot\limit}
%
\newcommand \Alpha A
\newcommand \Beta  B
\newcommand \Epsilon E
\newcommand \Tau   T
\begin{document}
% Why a blank page before title page?
\title{A Proposed Unification of Manifolds and Fibre Bundles}
\author{Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz}
\thanks{I wish to thank Milton Parnes, the Mathematics department of Wayne  State University and the Mathematics department
of the State University of New York at Buffalo for guiding my mathematical education}
\maketitle
body text
\end{document}
```

Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional page is caused by the `\thanks`, try to use it within `author{}`

```
\author{Shmuel (Seymour J.) Metz\thanks{I wish to thank Milton Parnes, the Mathematics department of Wayne  State University and the Mathematics department of the State University of New York at Buffalo for guiding my mathematical education}}
```